# Fancybox2: Title positioning and format

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Just getting started with Fancybox2.

The demo http://webdesignandsuch.com/posts/fancybox-download/fancyBox2/ I am playing with has the title as a centred black box, with white font, aligned one line below the image.

I want to show my title area within the bottom margin (ie black text on white background) so that whatever its height it expands to fit within the overall margin of the image and does not ingress into the image area.

I would also like to show 'Image x of y' on final line of the title area.

Can anyone give me a simple pointer as to which CSS or settings I need to change to achieve this.

Thanks

mcl

Comment: Why not open Firebug or Chromebug and find out yourself in sixty seconds?

Comment: What is meant by Image x of y' ? Is it the second question ?

Comment: I'm having a little trouble understanding where you want to position the black box. Do you mean so the box is the same width of the image?

Comment: Thanks for comments. In the lightbox created by Fancybox I wish my image to have a margin at the top, left and right of say 10px and the margin at the bottom to be big enough for my description, which may be one line or six lines and it has got to fit in the bottom margin of the lightbox.  My skills are not good enough to just use Chromebug to solve this question, otherwise I would have not asked the question.  I would also like to show as part of the description the current image's status in relation to the gallery.  Image 4 of 20 for example. I suppose I want a white box and not a black box.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fancybox").fancybox({
   helpers : { 
    title : { type : 'inside' }
   }, // helpers
   afterLoad : function() {
    this.title = (this.title ? '' + this.title + '<br />' : '') + 'Image ' + (this.index + 1) + ' of ' + this.group.length;
   } // afterLoad
  }); // fancybox
 }); // ready
</script>
```

If you set the title attribute on your links with `class="fancybox"`, it will display the title on the first line(s) and '`Image x of y`' in the final line. If you didn't specify any title, only '`Image x of y`' will be displayed.

**UPDATE**: For v2.0.6+ use `beforeShow` instead of `afterLoad`.

Comment: Many thanks. Now I understand a little of how Fancybox2 works, I can explore further.

Comment: you should use `beforeShow` instead of `afterLoad` if you want it to persist on more than just the first image

Comment: @cwd : correct for v2.0.6+ ... the post above was written for v2.0.3 and things have changed since then.

Comment: @cwd : I updated my answer to avoid further confusion (it's hard to keep current all the previous answers since plugins are evolving ;)

Comment: Great. Exact solution what I am searching for.