# Fancybox: Displaying the number of total images in the group

Tags: jquery, fancybox

With Fancybox, when the modal is open is there anywhere to dispay the number of images in the group? for example "Image 1 of 4", "Image 2 of 4", etc?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: @Sam I'm trying to choose the right lightbox for a project, Colorbox has this feature, but it doesnt have another feature that I need and fancybox is the closest.. so just asking its possible to display that text or not

Comment: I would definitely suggest colorbox, its got lots of useful features you can use. Is there something in particular it doesn't have that you need?

Comment: I added new title overlay for this. Check this:
`var pn = "<div style=\"color: #FFFFFF\">"+parseInt(this.index+1)+" / "+this.group.length+"</div>";
var pagenum = "<div class=\"fancybox-title fancybox-title-over-wrap\" style=\"bottom: auto; left: auto; -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px; -moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px; border-bottom-right-radius: 10px; padding: 8px 10px 6px 8px;\"><span class=\"child\"><div class=\"fancybox-title\">"+pn+"</div></span></div>";
var outer = $(".fancybox-skin").prepend(pagenum);`
Put this into afterShow

Comment: And you can use your own title seperately with this solution. My default title is used with 'inside' type, and this page number is used with modified 'over' now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using fancybox v1.3.4 use the API option `titleFormat` like :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".fancybox").fancybox({
  'titlePosition': 'over',
  'titleFormat': function(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {
     return '<span id="fancybox-title-over">Image ' + (currentIndex + 1) + ' of ' + currentArray.length + ' ' + title + '</span>';
   }
 }); // fancybox
}); // ready
```

If you are using fancybox **v2.0.6+** use the API option `beforeShow` like :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".fancybox").fancybox({
   helpers : { 
    title : { type : 'over' }
   }, // helpers
   beforeShow : function() {
    this.title = (this.title ? '' + this.title + '' : '') + 'Image ' + (this.index + 1) + ' of ' + this.group.length;
   } // beforeShow
 }); // fancybox
}); // ready
```

For older versions than v2.0.6 (v2.x only) use `afterLoad` instead.Check [this link for more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8663270/1055987)