# Fancybox 2 - Show image count as title

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I would like to have "Image 1 of 3" (relating to the images position inside it's linked gallery) inside the title of the Fancybox popup, something like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox-button").fancybox({
        prevEffect      : 'none',
        nextEffect      : 'none',
        closeBtn        : false,
        helpers     : {
            title   : { type : 'inside'},
            buttons : {}
        },
        afterLoad : function() {
                this.title = 'Image ' + (this.index + 1) + ' of ' + this.group.length + (this.title ? ' - ' + this.title : '');
            }
    });
});
```

I've searched far and wide, but can't find it anywhere.

EDIT

I managed to get it working on the first click using `afterLoad` however can't find similar functions for next and previous click.

Comment: Here is the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8663270/1055987, however if you are using fancybox v2.0.6+ then you need to use `beforeShow` instead of `afterLoad`.

Comment: Damnit, thats the answer I used but I didn't check the comments for 2.0.6! Cheers mate! Stick yours as an answer...

Comment: You could up vote the answer instead ;)

Answer (score 1):

### if you are using fancybox v2.0.6+ use the API option beforeShow like :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".fancybox").fancybox({
   helpers : { 
title : { type : 'over' }
}, // helpers
beforeShow : function() {
this.title = (this.title ? '' + this.title + '' : '') + 'Image ' + (this.index + 1) + ' of ' + this.group.length;
} // beforeShow
}); // fancybox
}); // ready`
```