# Adding a title to fancy box

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

Hi you probably think this is a dumb question but I am trying to get titles added to fancy box 2.  I know very little about javascript but have this at the bottom of my html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
});
</script>
```

AND if I try to add in

```
$(".fancybox")
.attr('rel', 'gallery')
.fancybox({
    beforeLoad: function() {
        this.title = $(this.element).attr('caption');
}
});
```

I get all sorts of syntax errors.

Site is: http://bit.ly/Wan5kr

Comment: try using single quote in  $(".fancybox").fancybox();

Comment: how do you add the two together?  Thanks :)

Comment: Check http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#useful No. 7 ... also as reference you could check http://stackoverflow.com/a/8663270/1055987

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your current script is :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fancybox").fancybox({
   helpers : { 
    title : { type : 'inside' }
   }, // helpers
   afterLoad : function() {
    this.title = (this.title ? '' + this.title + '<br />' : '') + 'Image ' + (this.index + 1) + ' of ' + this.group.length;
   } // afterLoad
  }); // fancybox
 }); // ready
```

... but should be (if you don't want to have "page 1 of 6") :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fancybox").fancybox({
   helpers : { 
    title : { type : 'inside' }
   } // helpers
  }); // fancybox
 }); // ready
```

On the other hand, if you prefer to use a `caption` attribute (because the `title` shows up as *tooltip* when you hover the images) the change `title` by `caption` like

```
<a href="images/Gallery/large/wing-back-chair.jpg" caption="Early 1900'....." rel="Sold" class="fancybox"><img width="304" height="350" alt="Winged back chair and ottoman" src="images/Gallery/tn/wing-back-chair.jpg"></a>
```

and use this script

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fancybox").fancybox({
   helpers : { 
    title : { type : 'inside' }
   }, // helpers
   beforeLoad: function() {
    this.title = $(this.element).attr('caption');
   }
  }); // fancybox
 }); // ready
```

Comment: Thankyou so much! Your expertise and help is very much appreciated :)

Comment: @JFK when i add your solution my thumbnails disappear, what could be the reason? JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/uZCC6/5191/

Answer (score 0):

One (and the simplest) option is to set the tittle attribute of the parent href.

Just like:

```
<a href="./bigimg/image.jpg" title="My custom title here" id="example">
    <img src="./thumbs/image.jpg" alt="thumbnail of image">
</a>
```

If you want to place the title inside the lightbox instead of right below it, you need to change the 'titlePostion' attribute. Just like this:

```
$("a.fancybox").fancybox({
    'titlePosition'  : 'inside'
});
```

Instead of 'over' you can also place it 'inside' or 'outside'. Outside is the default fancybox behavior. It positions your title right below (outside) of the lightbox. 'Over' places the title inside the lightbox, but on top of your picture with a dark alpha transparent background. 'Inside' places your title inside the lightbox, but below the picture, in the white lightbox border.

You can see the different results on the frontpage of [fancybox.net](http://fancybox.net/). See the three pictures under: "*Different title positions - 'outside', 'inside' and 'over'*"

Comment: Thanks for your response but I did this and I get one really long title.  I would like it to appear within the white frame like lightbox does.

Comment: I understand, you need to set the 'titlePosition' attribute then. I edited my earlier answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: @s.meijer : the OP is using fancybox v2.x and `titlePosition` is an option for fancybox v1.3.x which are not compatible.

Comment: Thanks everyone does this mean I should use lightbox intstead of fancybox?

Comment: @Amanda : did you check the links I posted as comments? ... of course you are free to use whatever you know how to use ;)

Comment: Thanks so much missed the link, just one more little thing please how do i get rid of image 1 of 3.

Comment: @Amanda : just remove the whole `afterLoad: function(){...}` callback and only use the `beforeLoad` callback as in your example above.

Comment: I am sooo sorry but I dont know what you mean.  I have this <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fancybox").fancybox({
   helpers : { 
    title : { type : 'inside' }
   }, // helpers
   afterLoad : function() {
    this.title = (this.title ? '' + this.title + '<br />' : '') + 'Image ' + (this.index + 1) + ' of ' + this.group.length;
   } // afterLoad
  }); // fancybox
 }); // ready
</script>

Which lines exactly should I remove?  Just this
function(){...}

Comment: @s.meijer I am also getting errors "document type does not allow <br> here.  Thanks for sticking with me on this.  I really appreciate it.