# The name (title) for the opened iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, fancybox-3

I'm using fancybox 3, but I ran into the problem, I can not either understand how to display the name in the opened iframe. Nowhere about this information have not found.
.
I do so.

```html
<a data-fancybox data-type="iframe" data-title="name iframe" title="name iframe" data-src="http://totaldict.ru/dictants/gorod-na-reke/" href="javascript:;">
    External page
</a>
```

```js
$("[data-fancybox]").fancybox({
toolbar: false,
smallBtn: true,
autoSize: true,
helpers: {
    title: {
        type: 'inside'
    },
    buttons: {}
},
iframe: {
    css: {
        width: '700px'
    }
},
});
```

What am I not so prescribed?

Comment: did u try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13176738/adding-a-title-to-fancy-box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
iframe : { 
    attr : {
        title : 'myTitle'
    } 
}
```

Comment: does not work, here's an example link.

https://codepen.io/gheka/pen/ypgGeG

Comment: You have provided perfectly working demo. The generated iframe tag contains `title="myTitle"` attribute. So, if this is not what you were looking for, I guess I do not understand your question.

Comment: Sorry, I'm wrong to put it.
For clarity, I attached 2 photos, they can see what I meant. Noted by rat rectangles.

1 photos - https://ibb.co/hV3QSG
2 photos - https://ibb.co/k24ogb

Comment: Sorry, this is not implemented in v3 (main reason is that these caption types would look weird while swiping and zooming). You can try to redesign (for example - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wpJdeZ), but it will not work the same, because caption in v3 is not directly under the content.