# fancybox image count title display

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have a page that uses fancybox 2.1.4 to display multiple different image galleries according to their respective `rel` attributes.

I've been struggling with getting the image count of each gallery displayed in the current image title.  After copying the method described by JFK via [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655213/fancybox2-title-positioning-and-format/8663270#8663270), the remaining script is becomes disabled.

My code is below. Can anyone help?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".fancybox").fancybox({
                helpers : {
                    title: {
                        type: 'outside'
                        }
                   }, // helpers
                   afterLoad : function() {
                    this.title = (this.title ? " + this.title + '<br />' : ") + 'Image ' + (this.index + 1) + ' of ' + this.group.length;
                   }                    
                });

            //start fade transition
            (function ($, F) {
                F.transitions.resizeIn = function() {
                    var previous = F.previous,
                        current  = F.current,
                        startPos = previous.wrap.stop(true).position(),
                        endPos   = $.extend({opacity : 1}, current.pos);

                    startPos.width  = previous.wrap.width();
                    startPos.height = previous.wrap.height();

                    previous.wrap.stop(true).trigger('onReset').remove();

                    delete endPos.position;

                    current.inner.hide();

                    current.wrap.css(startPos).animate(endPos, {
                        duration : current.nextSpeed,
                        easing   : current.nextEasing,
                        step     : F.transitions.step,
                        complete : function() {
                            F._afterZoomIn();

                            current.inner.fadeIn();//this rule controls the fadein of the next image
                        }
                    });
                };

            }(jQuery, jQuery.fancybox));

            $(".fancybox")
                /*.attr('rel', 'gallery')// am commenting this out so each gallery only loops through itself versus into the next gallery*/
                .fancybox({
                    nextMethod : 'resizeIn',
                    nextSpeed  : 200,//this rule controls the white flash action that happens just after an image is advanced

                    prevMethod : false,

                    helpers : {
                        title : {
                            type : 'outside'
                        }
                    }
                }); //end fade transition

        });         
    </script>
```

Comment: here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bzelip/HGxHg/

Comment: you are binding the selector `.fancybox` to fancybox twice so the second overrides the first one. Additionally, you should be using `beforeShow` instead of `afterLoad` for v2.1.x

Comment: Hey thanks for responding JFK. Sloppy of me not to have changed the beforeShow for this iteration. I think I've solved the double binding of .fancybox, but I'm still running into a problem.  If I remove lines 12-14 of this updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/bzelip/EwbN8/ - then fancybox works as planned (except w/out the image count per group).  I'm don't know I'm doing wrong with the code for generating image count display.

Comment: @BrianZ none of your jsfiddle shows your problem.. you might want to add the relative HTML and styles to it.

Comment: @rahulmaindargi thanks for be willing to help and advising to use jsfiddle.  This was my first time using it, I'll be sure to make better use of it next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your script is this line

```
beforeShow: function () {
    this.title = (this.title ? " + this.title + '<br />' : ") + 'Image ' + (this.index + 1) + ' of ' + this.group.length;
}
```

You said you were following my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8663270/1055987) but the same line in my code looks like :

```
beforeShow: function () {
    this.title = (this.title ? '' + this.title + '<br />' : '') + 'Image ' + (this.index + 1) + ' of ' + this.group.length;
}
```

Are you sharp enough to see the difference? ... so let's put them side by side in the same order (only the concerned part) :

```
this.title = (this.title ? " + this.title + '<br />' : ")   // you
this.title = (this.title ? '' + this.title + '<br />' : '') // me
```

The single quotes in my script are creating an empty space, while your double quotes are creating a string that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Thanks, all is working correctly now.  I tried multiple versions with single and double quotes to no avail before posting here.  I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @JFK any idea about this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30994366/changing-the-thumbs-position-responsiveness-in-fancybox