# Position thumbnails in fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fancybox

whenever you open the window on full-size, everything is okay. However when you re-size the window horizontally,  the thumbs shift and disappear. I want it to stay put like the large pop-up image, fixed in their position, so that the user on re-size would be able to see them by y-scroll.

Any help please?

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/ny9ytae5/4/

HTML:

```
<a caption="<h2>Image Header</h2><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>" rel="Sold" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="thumb1" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/4_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/4_s.jpg" alt="" /></a>

        <a class="fancybox hidden" data-fancybox-group="thumb1" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/3_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/3_s.jpg" alt="" /></a>

        <a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="thumb2" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_s.jpg" alt="" /></a>

        <a class="fancybox hidden" data-fancybox-group="thumb2" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_s.jpg" alt="" /></a>
```

UPDATE: i found that removing:

```
 'left': Math.floor($(window).width() * 0.5 - (obj.group.length / 2 * this.width + this.width * 0.5))
```

from jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js   solved the problem, but only if the browser is opened on full-size. If the user opens the site in a small window, the thumbnails won't even appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## New, simple solution:

As you want the thumbnails not to adapt to the screenwidth and not to be repositioned based on the currently active element, a very simple solution is to overrule the properties, that the `jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js` script is setting via inline styles.

> this way, you do not need to make any modification to the original `jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js`

Do so by adding these lines at the end of (!) `jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css` (or any other stylesheet, that is loaded after `jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css`:

```
/* added Rules: */

#fancybox-thumbs {
   width: 920px !important;
}

#fancybox-thumbs ul {
  left: inherit !important;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

And: voila... **[updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ny9ytae5/5/)**

---

## Old solution

As you already have found out, the fancybox thumbnail-helper uses `$(window).width()` to get the width of the screen and adapts the placement of the thumbnails accordingly.

I think you should modify your local version of `jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js` like this:

---

#### add fixedWidth variable

below this:

```
//Shortcut for fancyBox object
var F = $.fancybox;
```

add this:

```
var fixedWidth = 920;
```

---

#### Replace `$(window).width()` with `fixedWidth`.

So that this:

```
this.list.width(this.width * (obj.group.length + 1)).css('left', Math.floor($(window).width() * 0.5 - (obj.index * this.width + this.width * 0.5)));
```

becomes

```
this.list.width(this.width * (obj.group.length + 1)).css('left', Math.floor(fixedWidth * 0.5 - (obj.index * this.width + this.width * 0.5)));
```

and this:

```
'left': Math.floor($(window).width() * 0.5 - (obj.index * this.width + this.width * 0.5))
```

becomes:

```
'left': Math.floor(fixedWidth * 0.5 - (obj.index * this.width + this.width * 0.5))
```

---

I currently have no time to check out if it really works, but the chances are high ;-)

Good Luck!

Comment: that's what i want, but one thing, whenever i change an image, the thumbnails move , is there a way to prevent it from moving?

Comment: man just one final question please if possible, anyway to fix that description box, so that on window re-size the user can check it using the horizontal scroll?

Comment: any help on this? any help on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30994366/connecting-thumbnails-to-images-extracted-using-php   bounty:250