# Activate the menu only by clicking on the elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On my site I have a menu that has certain functionalities and animation:

- On mouse rollover there's a change in opacity for all elements of the menu except the one that is hovered above.
- When clicking on an element, it's marked by keeping its color and reducing the opacity of non-clicked elements.

Now these functions are working great, however the problem is that they can be all activated by clicking/hovering around the menu and above it, and not only on the elements.
Can it be fixed so that all the functions(without changing them) are activated just by clicking on an element in the menu?

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/atkumqpk/16/

HTML of the menu:

```
<div id="menu" class="menu">
    <ul class="headlines">
        <li id="item1">
            <button>aaaaaaaa</button>
        </li>
        <li id="item2">
            <button>bbbbbbb</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Too much code, you should leave only the most important.

Comment: @SergeyDenisov i agree,but leaving it or not, won't do anything to the problem i'm facing

Comment: I can't see the problem with `click`, only with CSS `:hover`. `click` works only on `<button>` now, isn't it?

Comment: @mikebrand , it won't fix the problem, but it will be easier for us to read your code. For instance, you can let only 2 `<li>` elements in your `<ul>`.

Comment: how about adding the id to the button tag instead of li?

Comment: @learning i tried it, however the problem remained

Comment: I certainly didn't understand the issue as I can't reproduce your problem. The animation only occurs when I click the elements. How can I reproduce your problem?

Comment: change the event from the li elements

Comment: @chiapa the menu has 4 animations/events : _ If clicked a slider fade in. _if an element clicked, the menu moves to the left. _Hovering over the menu will change the elements opacity. _Clicking on an element will have a change in opacity. Now i'm having a problem in the last 2 functionalities. Try hovering your mouse around the menu, there will be change in opacity. Try clicking next to "aaaaaaa" but not on it, the unclicked elements will change in opacity.... Now i want these functionalities but only bu hovering/clicking on an element of the menu, and not around it.

Comment: as long as I don't come very near to the button it will not receive the click. Actually as near as the elements text+padding+margin.

Comment: check this, may be can help you https://jsfiddle.net/vpd8on2a/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also did an update to your Fiddle:

> **[updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/atkumqpk/27/)**

---

My solution was to remove your click-event-handler for the `<LI>` elements and replaced it with click- and hover-events for the buttons:

Only two minimal changes to your css are needed.

The advantage of this solition (instead of relying on .headlines:hover-selector) is that your buttons can have different sizes and spaces between them. The area used to trigger your hover styles will always be the button-area and not the size of the surrounding `<li>`

---

```
// Removed Code

/*
var $li = $('.headlines li').click(function () {
    var state = !$(this).hasClass('active');
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('active', state);

    $li.removeClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active', state);
});
*/

// Added Code

var $headlines = $('.headlines');
var $headlinesLi = $('.headlines li');


$('.headlines button').each(function() {        //iterate over every 'button' in '.headlines':

    var $thisButton = $(this);                  // save (cache) the current jQuery-Button-Object
    var $parentLi=$thisButton.parent();         // save (cache) the parent <LI>
    var state = false;                          // set initial button-state to false


    $thisButton.click(function(){               // click-handler for the current Button:

        state = !state;                         // invert 'state'
        $headlinesLi.removeClass('active');     // remove .active-class on every <LI>
        $parentLi.toggleClass('active',state);  // set/remove .active-class on buttons parent <LI> as indicated by 'state'
        $headlines.toggleClass('active',state); // set/remove .active-class on .headlines indicated by 'state'

    });

    $thisButton.hover(                          //hover-handler for the current Button:

        function () {                           // routines for mouse-enter like events:
            $parentLi.addClass('hover');        // add .hover-class to buttons parent <LI>
            $headlines.addClass('hover');       // add .hover-class to .headlines
        },

        function () {                           // routines for mouse-leave like events:
            $parentLi.removeClass('hover');     // remove .hover-class to buttons parent <LI>
            $headlines.removeClass('hover');    // remove .hover-class to .headlines
        }

    );
});
```

This adds and removes `.hover` classes on `.headlines` and your buttons parent `<li>` elements.

---

In your CSS you only need to switch from from `:hover` pseudo-selektor to `.hover` class in the selection qualifier.

So switch from:

```
.headlines:hover li, .headlines.active li {
/* PARENT HOVER */
...

.headlines li:hover, .headlines li.active {
/* SINGLE HOVER */
...
```

to

```
.headlines.hover li, .headlines.active li {
/* PARENT HOVER */
...

.headlines li.hover, .headlines li.active {
/* SINGLE HOVER */
...
```

Voila.

Comment: the bounty is yours in 20 hrs. Perfect solution.. Thank you!!

Comment: check this if you have time http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31058459/position-thumbnails-in-fancybox

Answer (score 1):

Simply try to add event handlers to buttons directly and not `<li>` elements:

```
$(window).load(function () {

...

function AddEventHandlers()
{
        var btns = $('button');  // all buttons (set and use id or class
                                 // if you've other buttons on this page)


        for (int i = 0;i < btns .length; i++) {
            btns[i].click(function() {
                // your logic here;
            });
        }; 
};

    AddEventHandlers();
...

});
```

Comment: have you tried it? because it's edited like 5 times till now

Comment: I don't get it. Your fiddler example seem to work fine to me. What do you try to do then ?

Answer (score 1):

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/atkumqpk/24/), it looks like the problem was in your css:

```
.menu li {
    position: relative;
    top: 180px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

because of this rule, your li items was shifted down, but hovering in css triggered on .headlines (ul element), which position remains 180px higher, than it's child elements, so you get changing opacity when mouse higher than your menu items. And your ul element width was 100%, its children li elements width was the same (excluding margins), so your opacity also changes, when mouse was from left or right side of your actual text of menu.

Comment: man you solved it, however you altered the animation of the menu, can you please make it work with the previous animation? The menu should move to the left in this form /   ... And not like this |

Comment: just a question how to determine how much you want to extend the transition more to the left?

Comment: in css you can see something like "transition: left 2.0s ease-out" properties, so if you want one element to be moved to the left faster than another, just decrease time for transition.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the udpated fiddle:

```
[https://jsfiddle.net/atkumqpk/23/][1]
```

This is bacause you are targeting the li element for all events (click and hover) in script and css. Change your css to target button instead. Change the opacity for button. Give the :hover styling for buttons and not li. Also your li do not need a pointer cursor but the buttons do.

Comment: i tried it before, but the animation of the menu shifting left stopped

Comment: man the problems remain, you only manipulated the color of the menu