# Extracting images based on ID

Tags: php, html, css

I have a slider (flexslider) that i'm using to display images in the form shown in the below jsfiddle... I optimized the slider so that it extracts images dynamically from a certain directory. It worked and all images are being extracted.
Now in my folder images are named as 1023 ,  2045 , 304654, 50 etc...
How can i specify that images that start let's say with "1" (can be 14 , 1040,10000.100000 etc...) are the ones only extracted?

Update (more clarification): the reason i'm extracting based on the first digit of the name of each image, is that because i'm going to use the slider in all the elements of my menu. So that if i click on element "aaaa" images that start with 1 appear, if i click on "bbbbbb" images that start with 2 appear, and so on.

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/atkumqpk/1/

PHP code:

```
         function get_slide_images($folder, $images_per_slide = 10)
{

    $slide_images = false;

    if (file_exists($folder)) {

        // valid extensions
        $extensions = array(
            "jpg",
            "gif",
            "jpeg",
            "svg",
            "png",
            "bmp"
        );

        foreach (new DirectoryIterator($folder) as $file_key => $file) {

            // Don't bother
            if (!in_array($file->getExtension(), $extensions)) {
                continue;
            }

            // Grab file details
            $filename    = $file->getFilename();
            $file_folder = $folder . "/" . $filename;

            // Store the image to the Slide
            $slide_images[$filename] = "<img src='{$file_folder}' alt='{$file_folder}' />";

        }

        if (!empty($slide_images)) {
            ksort($slide_images);
            $slide_images = array_chunk($slide_images, $images_per_slide);
        }

    }
    return $slide_images;
}

//end of php 

        <div id="logo" class="logo" ><img src="logo.png"/></div>
        <p class="custom-class"><a href="">Go to the main website</a></p>

        <div id="menu" class="menu">
        <ul class="headlines">
              <li id="item1">
        <button>aaaaaaaa</button>
    </li>
    <li id="item2">
        <button>bbbbbbb</button>
    </li>
    <li id="item3">
        <button>ccccccc</button>
    </li>
    <li id="item4">
        <button>dddddddd</button>
    </li>
    <li id="item5">
        <button>eeeeeee eee.</button>
    </li>
    <li id="item6">
        <button>ffffff</button>
    </li>
    <li id="item7">
        <button>ggggggg</button>
    </li>

        </ul>
        </div>


     <div id="container">
<div id="first" class="inner-container">
   <div id="item11" class="item"> <a name="item11"></a>

                <div class="flexslider">

  <ul class="slides">



$slider_kvp = get_slide_images("images", 10);

/**
* Here we are going to generate the SLIDES
*/
if($slider_kvp) {

    $slider_list_html = array();

    foreach($slider_kvp as $slider_key => $slide_images) {

        $html_LI_list = "";
        $html_LI_list = "<li>";

        // Go through each image ...
        foreach($slide_images as $image_key => $image_value) {
            $html_LI_list .= $image_value;
        }

        $html_LI_list .= "</li>";

        $slider_list_html[$slider_key] = $html_LI_list;

    }

    // OUR SLIDES!
    $rendered_slider_list_html = implode(' ', $slider_list_html);
    echo "<ul class='slides'>{$rendered_slider_list_html}</ul>";

}



  </ul>
</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div id="second" class="inner-container">
      <div id="item22" class="item"> <a name="item22"></a>

              <div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">



$slider_kvp = get_slide_images("images", 10);

/**
* Here we are going to generate the SLIDES
*/
if($slider_kvp) {

    $slider_list_html = array();

    foreach($slider_kvp as $slider_key => $slide_images) {

        $html_LI_list = "";
        $html_LI_list = "<li>";

        // Go through each image ...
        foreach($slide_images as $image_key => $image_value) {
            $html_LI_list .= $image_value;
        }

        $html_LI_list .= "</li>";

        $slider_list_html[$slider_key] = $html_LI_list;

    }

    // OUR SLIDES!
    $rendered_slider_list_html = implode(' ', $slider_list_html);
    echo "<ul class='slides'>{$rendered_slider_list_html}</ul>";

}


  </ul>
</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You have images in the names of `1023 , 2045 , 304654, 50`. Okay. So what's `1` and what exactly you wanna do?

Comment: @PraveenKumar  the images are named with different numbers, i want to extract them based on the first digit of their fulll number.. e.g.: 10, 154, 10056, 1304... Are extracted because they start with 1

Comment: What's happening currently with your code?

Comment: @PraveenKumar what do you mean?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are various ways of achieving this, but one way would be to filter the filenames your function is iterating through. Instead of the `foreach (new DirectoryIterator($folder) as $file_key => $file) { ... }` block, you could do something like:

```
foreach (glob($folder.'/'.'1*') as $filename) {
    $slide_images[$filename] = "<img src='{$filename}' alt='{$filename}' />";
}
```

The `glob` bit matches everything inside `$folder` that starts with "1" (you could also limit it to, say, PNGs by specifying, eg. "1*.png")

This has the advantage of only looking at the files you actually want, which is more efficient than the alternative approach of iterating through everything and looking at its filename.

**Update:** if you want to be able to change the "starts with" filter (so it's not always "1"), you can add an extra argument to your function, like so:

```
function get_slide_images($folder, $images_per_slide = 10, $starts_with = '') {
```

...and then change the `foreach` part (above) so it uses it:

```
foreach (glob("{$folder}/{$starts_with}*") as $filename) {
```

...then you can call your function like this:

```
$slider_kvp = get_slide_images("images", 10, "1");
```

...where the third argument ("1") specifies what the files you want should start with. (If you call the function without a third argument, you'll get all files in the folder, as you currently do). So your `get_slide_images` function might look something like:

```
function get_slide_images($folder, $images_per_slide = 10, $starts_with = '')
{

    $slide_images = false;

    // valid extensions
    $extensions = array(
        "jpg",
        "gif",
        "jpeg",
        "svg",
        "png",
        "bmp"
    );

    // Implode the extensions array into a string:
    $extensions = implode(',', $extensions);

    if (file_exists($folder)) {

        // Get all the files with a valid extension in $folder:
        // (optionally filtered by $starts_with)
        foreach (glob($folder.'/'.$starts_with.'*.{'.$extensions.'}', GLOB_BRACE) as $filename) {
            $slide_images[$filename] = "<img src='{$filename}' alt='{$filename}' />";
        }

        if (!empty($slide_images)) {
            ksort($slide_images);
            $slide_images = array_chunk($slide_images, $images_per_slide);
        }

    }

    return $slide_images;
}
```

Comment: i'm going to use the slider in all the elements of my menu, so the results need to be different.. If i click on the first element of my menu, images that starts with 1 are extracted there, for the second element images with 2 etc... I believe your solution makes it so that wherever i put my slider the same elements will appear, how to change it?

Comment: You can just replace the bit where I've hard-coded "1" with a variable, and make that a third argument of your function. eg. `glob($folder.'/'.$filter.'*')`. Then call the function with, eg. `get_slide_images("images", 10, "1");` This should work fine as long as your filter is always the beginning of the filename (eg. "1", "2")

Comment: such as in the solution provided by doxick? because it didn't work, it still retrieved all images

Comment: No, this is a different approach (though the basic idea of adding an extra argument to your function to specify the filter is the same). DoXicK's approach is to loop through all filenames and match each of them against a pattern. This one is to specify the pattern when you fetch the images, so you only fetch the ones you need (which should be more efficient). I don't know why the pattern matching in DoXicK's solution didn't work, I'm afraid. I'm pretty sure the above should work, though.

Comment: anyway you can edit your post and show me how to do it.. I started with php a couple of days ago

Comment: can we open a chat conv?

Comment: I made a typo in my code. Because of that, condition checking did not work. My bad.

Comment: @Nick F thank you, i'll give you the bounty in 20hrs

Comment: @NickF just one question, your function is working, however i noticed that some images are not being extracted.. For example i have 14 images that starts with 9, but only extracting 13...What could be the problem?

Comment: @mikeb Thanks! Glad it helped. Re: your problem - could it be a problem with the file extension or something (eg. ".JPG" rather than ".jpg")? My guess would be that there's something different about the filename that isn't matched, but it's hard to say without seeing the list of files.

Comment: @NickF true that turned out to be the problem... Nick just one final thing, please answer me this. Let's say i want to extract images that starts with 128 and 147 in the same slider What should i do?
I tried $slider_kvp = get_slide_images("images", 10, "128,147");
but nothing

Comment: Well, this is getting a bit beyond the scope of the original question, tbh, but I think you might be able to get this working by adding curly brackets around the `$starts_with` variable in the `glob` expression. eg. `glob($folder.'/{'.$starts_with.'}*.{'.$extensions.'}', GLOB_BRACE)`

Comment: @NickF any help on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30994366/connecting-thumbnails-to-images-extracted-using-php   bounty:250

Answer (score 4):

Isn't the solution to this not just filtering it out on the server-side?

To make the function a bit more flexible (instead of filtering just '1'):

```
<?php
function get_slide_images($folder, $images_per_slide = 10, $pattern = "")
{
    $slide_images = false;

    if (!file_exists($folder))
        return $slide_images;

    // valid extensions
    $extensions = array(
        "jpg",
        "gif",
        "jpeg",
        "svg",
        "png",
        "bmp"
    );

    foreach (new DirectoryIterator($folder) as $file_key => $file) {
        // Don't bother
        if (!in_array($file->getExtension(), $extensions))
            continue;

        // Grab file details
        $filename    = $file->getFilename();
        if ($pattern && !preg_match($pattern, $filename))
            continue;
        $file_folder = $folder . "/" . $filename;

        // Store the image to the Slide
        $slide_images[$filename] = "<img src='{$file_folder}' alt='{$file_folder}' />";

    }

    if (!empty($slide_images)) {
        ksort($slide_images);
        $slide_images = array_chunk($slide_images, $images_per_slide);
    }
    return $slide_images;
}
```

and you can now run it with:

```
get_slide_images('images',10,'/^1/'); // get everything starting with 1
get_slide_images('images',10,'/^1234/'); // get everything starting with 1234
```

hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: i'm going to use the slider in all the elements of my menu, so the results need to be different.. If i click on the first element of my menu, images that starts with 1 are extracted there, for the second element images with 2 etc... Does your function do that?

Comment: Yes, it does that. Just fixed the code. Made a typo in the pattern checking condition.

Comment: dear it worked for the first element of my menu, however if i try it for the second element and put get_slide_images('images',10,'/^2/');  it extracts all elements. But if i change 2 to 1 it works

Comment: again fixed a typo. My logic was wrong. it should work now. If it still doesn't, i'll test it locally here.

Answer (score 4):

If you need a condition to check:

```
<?php
  function starts_with ($filename, $start)
    if (substr($filename, 0, 1) == $start)
      return true;
    return false;
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

in the php I'd just check

```
if ("1" !== substr($filename, 0, 1)) {
    continue;
}
```

during the `DirectoryIterator`

Comment: where exactly i should place it?

Comment: Just after `$filename    = $file->getFilename();` should be fine

Comment: @mikeb note that I changed the if slightly, it should have been `!==`

Comment: this is exactly what i want, however i'm going to place my slider in all the elements of my menu, that's why i'm extracting by first number... So now by placing the condition you provided where you specified, the same result will be in all the elements of the menu..How to change it so images that starts with 1 are only for slider in element aaaa of the menu and etc..

Comment: Right after your `// don't bother if { ... }`

Comment: @mikeb you'd either need to have multiple sliders and toggle display based on the button clicked, or when a button is clicked fetch the new data fromt he server and re-render the html using JS