# Gallery: Title with fancybox

Tags: fancybox, gallery, title

I can not bring up the titles in the gallery created with fancybox.

Use the latest version of fancybox.

here's the code:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $("a[rel=group]").fancybox({
                'transitionIn'      : 'none',
                'transitionOut'     : 'none',
                'titleShow': true,
                'titlePosition'  : 'over',
                'titleFormat'       : function(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {
                    return '<span id="fancybox-title-over">Image ' +  (currentIndex + 1) + ' / ' + currentArray.length + ' ' + title + '</span>';
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding: 5px;"><a rel="group" title="ciao bella" href="/img/leonardo/1_big.jpg"><img title="ciao bella" src="/img/leonardo/1.jpg" width="179" height="179"/></a></td>
            <td style="padding: 5px;"><a rel="group" href="/img/leonardo/2_big.jpg" ><img src="/img/leonardo/2.jpg" width="179" height="179"/></a></td>
            <td style="padding: 5px;"><a rel="group" href="/img/leonardo/3_big.jpg" ><img src="/img/leonardo/3.jpg" width="179" height="179"/></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding: 5px;"><a rel="group" href="/img/leonardo/4_big.jpg" ><img src="/img/leonardo/4.jpg" width="179" height="179"/></a></td>
            <td style="padding: 5px;"><a rel="group" href="/img/leonardo/5_big.jpg" ><img src="/img/leonardo/5.jpg" width="179" height="179"/></a></td>
            <td style="padding: 5px;"><a rel="group" href="/img/leonardo/6_big.jpg" ><img src="/img/leonardo/6.jpg" width="179" height="179"/></a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>  
</body>
```

how can I fix?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fancybox2: Title positioning and format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655213/fancybox2-title-positioning-and-format)

Comment: You are using the last version with options of a previous version which are not compatible